# USART1 Receive in STM32F103ZE

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usart

I was trying to implement the RS232 communication with STM32F103ZE.
I got the transmission working, but the reception is not working.
**I could get the reception and transmission works with UART4, but not with USART1,2,3 (Asynchronous mode)**
I tried with both interrupt and non interrupt methods.
I use CubeMX library to generate the code:

```
#include "main.h"

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void); 

int main(void)
{ 
  HAL_Init();  
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  MX_NVIC_Init();  

  while (1)
  { 
    uint8_t ch;
    HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);
    for (volatile long i = 0; i < 0xfffff; i++); 
  } 
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL8;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_NVIC_Init(void)
{ 
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{ 
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  } 
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE2 PE3 PE4 PE5
                           PE6 PE7 PE8 PE9
                           PE10 PE11 PE12 PE13
                           PE14 PE15 PE0 PE1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5
                          |GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9
                          |GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC13 PC14 PC15 PC0
                           PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4
                           PC5 PC6 PC7 PC8
                           PC9 PC10 PC11 PC12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0
                          |GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4
                          |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8
                          |GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PF0 PF1 PF2 PF3
                           PF4 PF5 PF6 PF7
                           PF8 PF9 PF10 PF11
                           PF12 PF13 PF14 PF15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA0 PA1 PA2 PA3
                           PA4 PA5 PA6 PA7
                           PA8 PA11 PA12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB1 PB2 PB10
                           PB11 PB12 PB13 PB14
                           PB15 PB5 PB6 PB7
                           PB8 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_10
                          |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14
                          |GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PG0 PG1 PG2 PG3
                           PG4 PG5 PG6 PG7
                           PG8 PG9 PG10 PG11
                           PG12 PG13 PG14 PG15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD8 PD9 PD10 PD11
                           PD12 PD13 PD14 PD15
                           PD0 PD1 PD2 PD3
                           PD4 PD5 PD6 PD7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15
                          |GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

} 
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{ 
  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  } 
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{ 
}
```

I haven't touched other parts of the code.
In all the examples I got, this is pretty much it.
Am I missing anything obvious?

PS: The connections are correct

Comment: Where are you initialising USART GPIOs (and which are they?)?

Comment: MX_GPIO_Init is the function to initialize GPIO.

Comment: It is calling from main()

Comment: I don't see any GPIOs initialised for UART function, just for analog input. What have I missed?

Comment: The UART's RX and TX pins are GPIO pins.  Those pins must be configured to the alternate function (AF) mode corresponding to the UART function.  And the GPIO port associated with those pins must be enabled.

Comment: Does it require clock enabled or configured in asynchronous mode?

Comment: Yes. I dont have synchrous support in the other device.

Comment: @kkrambo Yes. All these things are generated by the CubeMX software. Is there any possibility for voltage issues? Because the other device works at 5v and STM runs at 3v

Comment: The code you posted in your questions does not configure the UART's RX and TX pins for the UART alternate function.  If you think that CubeMX generated code to do that then show us that code and show us where you call that code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CubeMX so I'm just guessing here.  It looks like you've used CubeMX to configure every GPIO pin for analog mode.  Go back to CubeMX, find the GPIO pins that function as UART1 RX/TX, and configure those pins for UART1 mode instead of analog mode.  Then regenerate the code.

Comment: If you have an RS232 transceiver on both devices then the transceivers should take care of any voltage differences.  But don't worry about the voltage question until you get the GPIO pins configured correctly.

Comment: Oh okay. GPIO Pins are automatically configured with the CubeMX tool. It doesnt have any other options for GPIO. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/J4XLso2